# Создание и сохранение файлов Android;

Tags: java, android, io

Как создать папку на устройстве (`android/data/com.blabla.AppName`) и в последующем сохранять файлы в эту папку?

Comment: [Поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно писать именно в `android/data/com.blabla.AppName`, то (обработка исключений за Вами):

```
File externalAppDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName());
if (!externalAppDir.exists()) {
    externalAppDir.mkdir();
}

File file = new File(externalAppDir , "FileName.txt");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Далее стандартными средствами пишите данные в `file`.

Если нужно писать в поддиректории `android/data/com.blabla.AppName`, то для получения пути можно воспользоваться [методом](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

```
File getExternalFilesDir (String type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы про сохранение файлов в приватную директорию приложения, то вот пример записи `Hello world!` в текстовый файл `/data/data/<package>/files/file.txt`

```
String filename = "file.txt";
String outputString = "Hello world!";

try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
    }
    r.close();
    inputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```